# bash change user in shell script does not change env vars

Tags: bash

There's a user called `api` in which there's a file `test.sh` that should be executed with `root` user with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

su - api <<command
cd /home/api
source .bashrc
env
node -v
command
```

Output:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/home/api
LOGNAME=api
HOME=/home/api
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=screen
USER=api
SHLVL=1
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/api
OLDPWD=/home/api
_=/usr/bin/env
-bash: line 4: node: command not found
```

While if I manually switch to `api` user, the `env` is fine.

Note that `node` is installed with `NVM`.

When I run `su api` with `root`, and then run `env` command (I removed the unnecessary lines):

```
NVM_DIR=/home/api/.nvm
USER=api
PATH=/home/api/.nvm/versions/node/v18.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/NVM_BIN=/home/api/.nvm/versions/node/v18.0.0/bin
```

Any hints or helps for how can I switch to another user in a bash script and have the full `env`s of that user normally to run my desired commands?

**Update 1**

```
api@server:~$ pwd && ll
/home/api
total 72
drwxr-x---  9 api  www-data 4096 Aug  3 17:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root     4096 Jul  9 21:50 ../
drwxr-xr-x 14 api  api      4096 Aug  3 15:13 api/
-rw-------  1 api  api      2133 Aug  3 15:53 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 api  api       220 Jan  6  2022 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 api  api      3300 Jul  9 20:41 .bashrc
drwx------  2 api  api      4096 Jul 13 16:51 .cache/
drwx------  3 api  api      4096 Jul  9 20:50 .config/
-rw-------  1 api  api        20 Aug  3 15:12 .lesshst
drwxrwxr-x  5 api  api      4096 Jul 13 20:45 .npm/
drwxr-xr-x  8 api  api      4096 Jul  9 20:42 .nvm/
drwxrwxr-x  5 api  api      4096 Jul 13 20:51 .pm2/
-rw-r--r--  1 api  api       807 Jan  6  2022 .profile
drwx------  2 api  api      4096 Aug  3 15:24 .ssh/
-rw-rw-r--  1 api  api       111 Aug  3 15:25 test.sh
-rw-------  1 api  api      8207 Aug  3 17:51 .viminfo
```

contents of `.bashrc` (if that's a lot, please remove the extra parts or tell me to remove):

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

The `.profile` contains nothing important:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I even ran this:

```
root@server:~# su -l api -c 'cd /home/api && source .bashrc && source .profile && env && node -v'
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/home/api
LOGNAME=api
HOME=/home/api
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=screen
USER=api
SHLVL=1
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/api
OLDPWD=/home/api
_=/usr/bin/env
**-bash: line 1: node: command not found**
```

Also when I login to `api` user:

```
api@server:~$ echo $PATH
/home/api/.nvm/versions/node/v18.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254788/discussion-on-question-by-saeed-bash-change-user-in-shell-script-does-not-change); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue can be solved using different methods,I suggest few methods that I hope will be helpful to you, in first method, you can use the `runuser` instead of `su` and the `runuser` is similar to `su`,but it sets up the environment variables of the specified user properly!

```
#!/bin/bash

runuser -l api -c 'cd /home/api && source .bashrc && env && node -v'
```

and by using the `-l`, your script will switch to the `api` user and load their login environment, including the correct `PATH` and other environment variables, now you are able to run `node -v` successfully!

in second method you can use the `sudo -i -u` that switches to the `api` user and starts a new interactive bash session with that user's environment variables!

```
sudo -i -u api bash <<EOF
cd /home/api
source .bashrc
env
node -v
EOF
```

and in third method you can use `su -l` that simulate a full login for the `api` user

```
su -l api -c 'cd /home/api && source .bashrc && env && node -v'
```

**update:**

Ok, I think you can try add the NVM initialization lines directly to the script before executing the `node` to ensure that the NVM environment is set up correctly for the `api` user before executing the `node`!

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

su - api -c '
export NVM_DIR="/home/api/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
cd /home/api
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.profile
env
node -v
'
```

if it's not work again update your code like this and don't forget to change `~` with the absolute path to the home directory of the `api` user

```
su - api -c 'cd /home/api && source ~/.bashrc && source ~/.profile && env && node -v'
```

Comment: Thanks, but in all of these methods, I see `-bash: line 1: node: command not found` and also `env` is not corrected.

Comment: @Saeed `.bashrc` is not the only dotfile there is, and if your PAM configuration is different between `su` and other login mechanisms, there may be differences in the variables that are set even _before_ the shell starts execution.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no, I edited the question. There are other dot files.

Comment: @Saeed check my answer again plz

Comment: @Freeman thanks sir, the update works. But it's odd for me for adding the `export` and `NVM` lines directly. I'm happy that it works, but I'm curious about the reason why without that it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Saeed because when you use the su command to switch to another user, it starts a new shell session for that user. This new shell session does not automatically inherit the environment variables and settings from the original shell session and by adding the export and NVM initialization lines directly in the script, you are explicitly setting the necessary environment variables and initializing NVM for the new shell session of the api user!